# Unpredictable behavior on first login after installing 12.04

Tags: installation, login

I installed 12.04.

After first login I can see the Ubuntu screen which does not respond as expected. It goes partially black when I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> and freezes, and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keys the terminal does not appear.

I had the same version of Ubuntu on this machine which is a Sony VAIO. Had to reinstall as partition space on tmp was not sufficient.

Now I have 30GB on root ext4, 5GB on swp and another 25GB on ext4.

I do not understand what has caused this issue suddenly.

**Edit:** On resetting unity I get this message (I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then entered `unity --reset`):

```
(compix:2172):GCong-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: addertion
  gconf_valid_key(dirname, NULL) failed
ERROR 2012-10-21 unity.launcher.trashlaunvcericon.cpp:62
  Could not create file monitor for trash url: Opetation not supported
compiz (core) - Warn: Unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc0009e
compiz (core) - Warn: This should never happen. You should probably file a bug about this.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of the same issue going on.  It appears that Unity 3D is not working properly.  I have not been able to figure out what the problem is nor how to fix it.  There are so many posts on the topic.

Good news is I do have a work around, using Unity 2D.  At the login screen, right click the Ubuntu circle thing to the right of your name, click Ubuntu 2D, and login as normal.

Here is what I get when I execute `unity --reset`

```
mmorris@ion:~$ unity --reset
WARNING: no current gconf profile set, assuming unity
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...yes
[LOG]: Moving Internal Files
[LOG]: Copying subdirectory from /home/mmorris/.compiz/session to /home/mmorris/.compiz-1/session
[LOG]: Copied file /home/mmorris/.compiz/session/1099d83abd38142b6b135126642044748200000020980043 to /home/mmorris/.compiz-1/session/1099d83abd38142b6b135126642044748200000020980043
[LOG]: Successfully moved internal files
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2000004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1200002

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1400002

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x30000b8

Initializing composite options...done
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 55
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 56
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 59
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 58
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:2077): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed

** (process:2161): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code4: Failed to create file '/home/mmorris/.config/dconf/user.CAEZMW': No such file or directory

** (process:2166): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code4: Failed to create file '/home/mmorris/.config/dconf/user.VPOGMW': No such file or directory

** (process:2169): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code4: Failed to create file '/home/mmorris/.config/dconf/user.B6WGMW': No such file or directory
WARN  2012-10-26 10:51:51 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:139 Unable to load GDesktopAppInfo for 'ubiquity-gtkui.desktop'
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00090!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00096!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00099!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
WARN  2012-10-26 10:51:53 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2012-10-26 10:51:53 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2012-10-26 10:51:53 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
Initializing annotate options...done
Initializing blur options...done
Initializing clone options...done
Initializing colorfilter options...done
Initializing commands options...done
Initializing cube options...done
Initializing imgjpeg options...done
Initializing kdecompat options...done
Initializing mag options...done
Initializing neg options...done
Initializing obs options...done
Initializing opacify options...done
Initializing put options...done
Initializing resizeinfo options...done
Initializing ring options...done
Initializing rotate options...done
Initializing scaleaddon options...done
Initializing screenshot options...done
Initializing shift options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing switcher options...done
Initializing thumbnail options...done
Initializing water options...done
Initializing winrules options...done
Initializing wobbly options...done
ERROR 2012-10-26 10:51:55 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Starting gtk-window-decorator
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
WARN  2012-10-26 10:52:43 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.view' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application283295483

ERROR 2012-10-26 10:52:45 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2012-10-26 10:53:09 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.view' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application283295483

ERROR 2012-10-26 10:53:11 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```